# SiteAuth UserAgent Test Class Creation

Tags: apex, unit-test, oauth2, authentication, oauth

I'm new in creating SiteAuth userAgent test class creation.

`public SiteAuthControl() {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            string userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT');
            if(userAgent.contains('internet explorer')) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, SA_Constants.UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER));
                browserSupported = false;
            }
            else {
                browserSupported = true;
            }
        }
    }`

In this line of code, what could be the corresponding test class? Hope you could help me with this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything that requires the `!Test.isRunningTest()` guard so I suggest you remove it.

Then in your test case you can have:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('USER-AGENT', '... internet explorer ...');
```

and:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('USER-AGENT', '... something else ...');
```

to test both conditions.

Personally, I would also take the cautious approach of allowing the 'USER-AGENT' header to be missing altogether:

```
if(userAgent != null && userAgent.contains('internet explorer')) {
```

though AFAIK it never will be.

Take care with the string you test; `contains` is case sensitive so something like 'MSIE' may be a better choice - see [Internet Explorer User Agent Strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/).